# reapp to cordova to xcode to iphone images not showing up

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have built a fairly simple i-phone app using reapp.  When I run the the app on local host it works perfectly.

I followed the guide to install the app on i-phone but now when I run it from xcode the app works however none of the images have loaded.

My images are sitting in a folder inside assets called img.

Has anyone experienced this issue and does anyone know a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I worked it out, you just have to change the target from assets/images to images.